# Formik - highlight input green when field is valid

Tags: reactjs, formik

Is there an easy way to change the input border color to green when a field is valid in Formik? I had trouble finding a good example of this - I'm not sure if there's a valid variable for the field?

I already have validations errors showing up in red using`{errors.fieldname}`, but also want the field border to turn green (or have some type of green checkmark) as soon as the field is valid.
I'm using `Yup` schema validation if that matters.

Comment: Maybe show us some code to see how / when you're applying validation, which formik components you're using exactly?

Comment: I think your post you deleted was sort of what I was looking for `!errors.fieldname`  - that will work if there's no errors, but it may or may not be passing Yup validation. I can try to put together some code samples.

Comment: yes i deleted it because i realize its such a generic answer bc your question doesnt have any code, so I wasn't sure how to properly answer with a real code example.  I can undelete it if you found it helpful or want to use it as a jumping off point.

Comment: `!errors.fieldName` does validate that it is passing Yup validation, if the field has been validated yet. The ways to ensure that is validated at all times are:
(1) If it applies to this situation, you can set `validateOnMount` to true, so that everything is validated from the getgo. Alternatively, you can check `touched.fieldname` and only make the input green if `touched.fieldname && !errors.fieldname`.
(2) Be sure to pass `handleBlur` to the input so that validation gets run on every blur event in addition to every change event.

Answer (score 2):

You could change the css to apply a green border if `!errors.fieldname` on form validation.  You can  play with `validateOnBlur` and `validateOnChange` within the `Formik` component, so that validation is happening either as you type or as you blur out of a field.

Perhaps you can put an `onBlur` function on your input, and check the errors.  If there are no errors on blur, you can set a state variable to capture the fact that the field is valid, and use that to apply a className.

```js
state = {
  greenborder: {
    fieldName1: null,
    fieldName2: null,
  }
}

handleBlur = fieldName => {
  if (!errors[fieldName]) {
    this.setState({
      greenborder: {
        ...this.state.greenborder,
        [fieldName]: true
      }
    })
  }
}

// in render:
<input 
  onBlur={() => handleBlur(fieldName1) } 
  type="text" 
  className={this.state.greenboder.fieldName1 ? 'green' : ''}
>
```

This is just a generic idea.  You could also attach the event to the `onChange`.  You can also use the [`validate` prop](https://formik.org/docs/guides/validation#validate-1) of the `Field` component.  Hopefully that gets your started.